# Fetch data in single Eloquent Query laravel using relations?

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, eloquent

I am working on social app front end Angualar, Backend laravel and with database Mongodb. I have  model like:

```
Hoots
-----------------
 - _id
 - content
 - publish_id

Article 
-----------------
 - _id
 - content
 - publish_id

Story
-----------------
 - _id
 - content
 - publish_id

Publish
-----------------
 - _id
 - post_id
 - type
 - user_id
```

Post id in publish belongs to _id in hoots , article and story , where type signify wheather it is hoot , article or story.

I have Model like this

```
//Article model 
class Article extends Eloquent {

  public function getpublish(){
     return $this->hasMany('Publish','post_id');
    }
  }
 //Story model 
 class Story extends Eloquent {

  public function get_publish(){
     return $this->hasMany('Publish','post_id');
    }
  }

 //Hoots model 
 class Hoots extends Eloquent {

  public function get_publ(){
     return $this->hasMany('Publish','post_id');
    }
  }

//Publish model 
 class Publish extends Eloquent {

  public function getdata(){

     return $this->BelongsTo('Hoots','Article','Story','publish_id');
    }
  }
```

I am using

```
  Publish::with('getdata')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

using this i can only get publish data along with post_id corresponding data in one model i.e hoots only. I want this from all three tables.

I want to fetch publish model data with their corresponding post_id data.How can i accomplish this o single query using eloquent.

Comment: its really hard to work out what you are asking for. Can you provide a  table of the outcome you expect?\

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I have updated code. Kindly Review.how can i get publish model data along with post_id corresponding data from three different model having foreign key publish_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you haven't got your relationships setup correctly;

```
//Publish model 
 class Publish extends Eloquent {

  public function hoot(){

     return $this->HasMany('Hoots','publish_id');
    }
  }

  public function article(){

     return $this->HasMany('article','publish_id');
    }
  }

  public function story(){

     return $this->HasMany('stort','publish_id');
    }
  }

Publish::with(array('hoot', 'story', 'article'))->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: I don't why but this thing is not working , I am only gettting Id not the content? I am specifying table name inside joins as you illustrated above. database i am using is mongodb

Comment: Awesome man. I was trying same thing but with belongsto. hasmany does th charm. Thanks